# Python Queue suddenly empty

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to run a couple of calculations concurrently based on [this example](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/16/python-parallelizing-cpu-bound-tasks-with-multiprocessing/). I extended it in the way that instead of just a simple function, I'm running some external software via subprocess. It's run with Python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.16.0-30-generic x86_64).

There is a Queue involved to keep track of result outputs. This Queue is supposed to get filled, but appears to be empty after calculations are done.

The simplified code looks like this:

```
import subprocess, shlex, os, random, pickle
from Queue import Queue
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep

def mp_solve(problems, nprocs):
    def worker(problem, out_q):
        outdict = []
        cmd = "..." + problem
        args = shlex.split(cmd)
        output,error = subprocess.Popen(args,stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr= subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
        outdict = [str(problem), str(output)]
        out_q.put(outdict)
        print out_q.empty() #prints False

    out_q = Queue() #create Queue
    procs = []

    for i in range(nprocs):
        p = Process(
                target=worker,
                args=(problems[i][1], out_q))
        procs.append(p)
        p.start()

    sleep(10) #calculations are limited to 3 seconds through a parameter passed to external program

    print out_q.empty() #prints True

    resultlist = []
    for i in range(nprocs):
        print "going to Q" + str(i)
        try:
            resultlist.append(out_q.get())
        except Queue.Empty:
            print "Queue empty"


mp_solve(list_of_problems, 10)
```

The output of this will be

```
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
True
going to Q0
```

After the last command, the session window is rendered useless. I can type in it, but nothing will happen and even Ctrl + C has no effect. I then just close the ssh session.

I'm fairly new to multiprocessing and I can't figure out why the Queue appears to get filled correctly (as seen from the False returned) but is then empty. Note that Queue.Empty never seems to catch. Any ideas how to get me back on the right track?

Comment: Looks like you have a fork bomb.  Have you seen the `if __name__ == '__main__'` in all the examples for `multiprocessing`?

Comment: Where are you calling mp_solve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sharing a queue among several processes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908781/sharing-a-queue-among-several-processes)

Comment: @ReutSharabani: isn't that specific to using `Pool`?

Comment: @cdarke , not as far as I know. The idea is to do some sort of boxing to globalize objects to other processes. As I understand it - **any** other processes. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @ReutSharabani:  only I've passed queue objects in the function call without issue.  I'm fairly sure this is a fork bomb problem, the code is probably being called by every child process because there is no check on that.

Comment: There's no `join()` either

Comment: wouldn't a fork bomb cause many more processes? also, sending the queue won't help because all objects are copied to different memort locations on `fork`

Comment: *After the last command, the session window is rendered useless*

Comment: @cdarke, I thought the output would be much longer than presented if that was the case.

Comment: Yes, it's not a fork bomb: the problem is simply that the OP isn't using a process-shared queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Queue` object from the `Queue` module isn't suitable for multiprocessing: it's intended only for communication between threads in the same process.  Use the `Queue` object from the `multiprocessing` module instead.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
```

That should solve the immediate problem.  Here are a couple of other notes:

- `out_q.get()` is a blocking call: if there's nothing in the queue then it will wait until there is.  So in your code above, the `Empty` exception will never be raised.  For a non-blocking version, try `out_q.get(block=False)`.  Alternatively, you could specify a timeout: `out_q.get(timeout=10.0)`.
- It's good practice to *join* your child processes before your main process exits.  Call `proc.join()` on each process.  As dano points out in the comments, there's a possibility of deadlock if you try to join the processes *before* emptying the queue (see the warning [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues)), so you probably want to do this at the very end of your `mp_solve` function.
- It's also good practice to guard your main code with an `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.  It won't make a difference on Linux (under Python 2.7), but without it your code won't run correctly on Windows.
- Again for cross-platform compatibility, you should move the nested `worker` function out to module level.  For the code to run on Windows, the `worker` function needs to be pickleable, and nested functions aren't pickleable.

Comment: One note on the second point - if your child process is putting a large amount of data into the output queue, trying to `join` the child before pulling data out of the `Queue` could cause a deadlock. See the warning [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues).

Comment: @dano: I'd forgotten about that detail.  Thanks.