# Pass Value("i", 0) to processs

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this code (it is snippet from my program):

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, cpu_count, Pool, Value, Lock

def grab_future_products(p, test):
    print("Starting procces %s" % p)

if __name__ == "__main__": # Main program
    n = 4
    test = Value('i', 0)
    pool = Pool(processes=n) # n processes per every CPU core

    for i in range(n):
        pool.apply_async(grab_future_products, args=(i, test))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

If I run it with `python test.py` I got no output, no errors, just nothing.
I wanted to use variable test as shared integrer between all processes so I can do in another process something like:

```
if test.value == X:
    break
```

But interesting is that if I replace `args=(i, test))` with `args=(i, 1))`, it will work as desired.
So my question is, why I can not pass `Value()` object into process? And how I can solve this problem?
Many thanks.

Comment: Nope, still nothing. And I tried `pool.apply_async(grab_future_products(i, test))` , but it will run one proccess after one, not in paraller.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my previous comment by mistake...for context, I was saying : "What about `pool.apply_async(grab_future_products, (i, test))` ?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use [multiprocessing.Manager](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes), as also mentioned here: [Sharing a result queue among several processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908781/sharing-a-result-queue-among-several-processes):

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, cpu_count, Pool, Value, Lock

def grab_future_products(p, test):

    print("Starting procces %s, value=%i" % (p, test.value))

if __name__ == "__main__": # Main program
    n = 4
    pool = Pool(processes=n) # n processes per every CPU core
    m = Manager()
    v = m.Value('i', 0)
    for i in range(n):
        res=pool.apply_async(grab_future_products, args=(i, v))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```