# Multiprocessing in Python not calling the worker functions

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm fairly new to multiprocessing and I have written the script below, but the methods are not getting called. I dont understand what I'm missing.

What I want to do is the following:

1. call two different methods asynchronously.
2. call one method before the other.

   ```
       # import all necessary modules
       import Queue
       import logging
       import multiprocessing
       import time, sys
       import signal

       debug = True

       def init_worker():
           signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)

       research_name_id = {}
       ids = [55, 125, 428, 429, 430, 895, 572, 126, 833, 502, 404]
       # declare all the static variables
       num_threads = 2  # number of parallel threads

       minDelay = 3  # minimum delay 
       maxDelay = 7  # maximum delay 

       # declare an empty queue which will hold the publication ids
       queue = Queue.Queue(0)


       proxies = []
       #print (proxies)

       def split(a, n):
           """Function to split data evenly among threads"""
           k, m = len(a) / n, len(a) % n
           return (a[i * k + min(i, m):(i + 1) * k + min(i + 1, m)]
                   for i in xrange(n))
       def run_worker(
               i,
               data,
               queue,
               research_name_id,
               proxies,
               debug,
               minDelay,
               maxDelay):
           """ Function to pull out all publication links from nist
           data - research ids pulled using a different script
           queue  -  add the publication urls to the list
           research_name_id - dictionary with research id as key and name as value
           proxies - scraped proxies
           """
           print 'getLinks', i
           for d in data:
               print d
               queue.put(d)




       def fun_worker(i, queue, proxies, debug, minDelay, maxDelay):
           print 'publicationData', i
           try:
               print queue.pop()
           except:
               pass




       def main():
           print "Initializing workers"
           pool = multiprocessing.Pool(num_threads, init_worker)
           distributed_ids = list(split(list(ids), num_threads))
           for i in range(num_threads):
               data_thread = distributed_ids[i]
               print data_thread
               pool.apply_async(run_worker, args=(i + 1,
                       data_thread,
                       queue,
                       research_name_id,
                       proxies,
                       debug,
                       minDelay,
                       maxDelay,
                   ))

               pool.apply_async(fun_worker,
                   args=(
                       i + 1,
                       queue,
                       proxies,
                       debug,
                       minDelay,
                       maxDelay,
                   ))

           try:
               print "Waiting 10 seconds"
               time.sleep(10)

           except KeyboardInterrupt:
               print "Caught KeyboardInterrupt, terminating workers"
               pool.terminate()
               pool.join()

           else:
               print "Quitting normally"
               pool.close()
               pool.join()

       if __name__ == "__main__":
           main()
   ```

The only output that I get is

```
      Initializing workers
      [55, 125, 428, 429, 430, 895]
      [572, 126, 833, 502, 404]
      Waiting 10 seconds
      Quitting normally
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues:

1. You're not using `multiprocessing.Queue`
2. If you want to share a queue with a subprocess via `apply_async` etc, you need to use a manager [(see example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908781/sharing-a-result-queue-among-several-processes).

However, you should take a step back and ask yourself what you are trying to do. Is `apply_async` is really the way to go? You have a list of items that you want to map over repeatedly, applying some long-running transformations that are compute intensive (because if they're just blocking on I/O, you might as well use threads). It seems to me that `imap_unordered` is actually what you want:

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(num_threads, init_worker)
links = pool.imap_unordered(run_worker1, ids)
output = pool.imap_unordered(fun_worker1, links)
```

`run_worker1` and `fun_worker1` need to be modified to take a single argument. If you need to share other data, then you should pass it in the initializer instead of passing it to the subprocesses over and over again.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I also want to start multiple processes. is apply_async the right way to do that? I will read more on impa_unordered