# Multiprocessing Queue need Manager?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, queue, multiprocessing, deadlock

Why program A deadlock but program B runs fine?

Both uses a queue to pass result between main process and sub-processes. Both wait for all sub-processes to end before retrieving the results from the queue.

In the actual program, I need a queue to pass streams of results between steps. This is for working on results when the results are generated and before one of the step completes.

Changing the `mp.queue` in program A to a queue of a `mp.Manager` would fix the deadlock. But using manager seems to have performance penalty, because the manager is managed by the main process.

Program A (deadlocks without manager):

```
import multiprocessing as mp
def worker(q, i): 
    q.put(i)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = mp.Queue()

    # Start sub-processes
    p = mp.Pool()
    for i in range(4):
        p.apply_async(worker, args=(q, i)) 

    # wait till all workers complete their task.
    p.close()
    p.join()

    # Get results from queue
    for i in range(4):
        print(q.get())
```

Program B is my simplification of a program at (https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html) below the line "basis for code meeting your own specific requirements", and it doesn't use a manager ...

Program B:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
def worker(q, i):
    q.put(i)

if __name__  == "__main__":
    q = mp.Queue()

    # Start sub-processes
    ws = []
    for i in range(4):
        w = mp.Process(target=worker, args=(q, i))
        ws.append(w)
        w.start()

    # wait till all workers complete their task.
    for w in ws:
        w.join()

    # Get results from queue
    for i in range(4):
        print(q.get())
```

Comment: congratulations: you seem to have triggered undefined behaviour using python. the docs advise to use a Manager, that should be self explanatory why you must use it.

Comment: try replacing `p.apply_async` by `p.apply` and Python will recommend you to use a manager. I think `apply_async` is the most sensitive function. Won't work at all without a manager.

Comment: queue occasionally has corrupted data without manager. i guess shared memory is the way to go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894791/use-numpy-array-in-shared-memory-for-multiprocessing