# How multiple multiprocessing queues pass a value from one function to another

Tags: python, multiprocessing

The code posted below, while does not crash, does not return `os.getpid()` value from `foo` function. How to pass a value over the multiple queue objects so it could be printed with a `print(queue.get())` command?

```
import time, multiprocessing, os

def foo(*args):
    outside_queue = args[0]
    logger = multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()
    logger.warning(os.getpid())
    outside_queue.put(os.getpid())
    time.sleep(30)

class Object(object):
    def run(self, *args):
        outside_queue = args[0]

        items = dict()
        for i in range(5):
            queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
            proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=foo, args=(queue,))
            items[proc] = queue
            proc.start()

        for proc, queue in items.items():
            if not queue.empty():
                outside_queue.put(queue.get())

for i in range(2):
    obj = Object()
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=obj.run, args=(queue,))
    proc.start()
    while True:
        proc.join(1)
        if not proc.is_alive():
            break

        if not queue.empty():
            print(queue.get())
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9928191/7675174) regarding using  a `multiprocessing.Manager()` help? I can't execute your script without generating a RuntimeError.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is a synchronize problem, in `Object.run`, between starting the child processes and getting results from the queue, there is no guarantee child process has put something into the queue, you have to wait explicitly, use `Event`, for example:

```
def foo(outside_queue, evt):
    outside_queue.put(os.getpid())
    evt.set()

class Object(object):
    def run(self, *args):
        outside_queue = args[0]
        items = dict()
        for i in range(5):
            evt = multiprocessing.Event()
            queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
            proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=foo, args=(queue, evt))
            items[proc] = queue
            proc.start()
            evt.wait(None)
            ...
```