# How to use a Pool of Workers with a Queue in python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I am currently trying to set up a Parameter Study with multiprocessing, but I don't understand exactly how to use a queue to get the results back to the main process.

Can somebody please help and tell me, why my example doesn't work?

```py
    import numpy as np
    import multiprocessing as mp
    from queue import Empty


    def run(q1):

        q1.put({'val':np.random.random(), 'ErrFlag':False})


    if __name__ == '__main__':

        q = mp.Queue()

        pool = mp.Pool(processes = 10)

        results = []

        for i in range(50):
            pool.apply_async(run, (q,))

        pool.close()
        pool.join()

        while True:
            try:
                res = q.get(timeout = 1)

                results.append(res['val'])

            except Empty:
                break

        print(f'result: {repr(np.array(results))}\n')
```

When executing this, I only get an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [Sharing a result queue among several processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908781/sharing-a-result-queue-among-several-processes)

You should use a manager to make your queue accessible to the different workers:

```
pool = mp.Pool(processes=10)
m = mp.Manager()
q = m.Queue()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.