# calling apply async inside apply async python function

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

i am trying to call a pool with inside apply_async function , i get error of serialize object when i tried to pass one function the pool of another function so i moved the second pool to be global but still it not worked for me, what am i missing ?
my code :

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
b_pool = Pool(1)

def func_a(i):
    global b_pool
    print "a : {}".format(i)
    try:
        res = b_pool.apply_async(func_b, args=(i,))
    except Exception as e:
        print e

def func_b(i):
    print "b : {}".format(i)
    file = "/home/ubuntu/b_apply.txt"
    f = open(file, "a")
    f.write("b : {}".format(i))
    f.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a_pool = Pool(1)
    for i in range(10):
       res =  a_pool.apply_async(func_a,args=(i,) )

    a_pool.close()
    a_pool.join()

    b_pool.close()
    b_pool.join()
```

in this code only a is printing 0 -9 and b not printing not even to file.
i am using python 2.7

Comment: Close and join of "b_pool" must be done in "func_a" because this is a different pool in a different process than "b_pool" in main process.

Comment: not excatly waht i want , i want that b will add function to the pool after a in ending , and did not wirk can you please add code

Comment: One way can be to create a `multiprocessing.Queue` and send it through an `initializer` function when creating the first `Pool`. The initializer stores the queue object (which is then shared among main process and created workers) and the workers send job data for the `b_pool` back to the main process through the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the queue was good direction , just that that multiprocessing.Queue can't be passed like this but Manager.Queue  is the correct way of doing this , my code that worked :

```
from multiprocessing import Pool,Manager
def func_a(i,q):
    print "a : {}".format(i)
    try:
        q.put(i)
    except Exception as e:
        print e


def func_b(i,q):
    i = q.get()
    print "b : {}".format(i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = Manager()
    q = m.Queue()
    a_pool = Pool(1)
    b_pool = Pool(1)

    for i in range(10):
        res = a_pool.apply_async(func_a,args=(i,q,) )
        res_2 = b_pool.apply_async(func_b, args=(i,q,))

    a_pool.close()
    a_pool.join()

    b_pool.close()
    b_pool.join()
```

this answer [Sharing a result queue among several processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908781/sharing-a-result-queue-among-several-processes) was very helpful