# Can I pass queue object in multiprocessing pool starmap method

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

There are many questions in SO regarding passing multiple arguments in python multiprocessing Pool's starmap method. But what I want to ask is if I can send a queue object in the method which can be shared between different processes?

I am able to do this using threading and multiprocessing Process method, but not using Pool's starmap method.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Pool


def get_data(pageNo,q):
    q.put(pageNo*pageNo)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = Queue()
    p = {}
    no_pages = 5
    pool_tuple = [(x,q) for x in range(1,no_pages)]
    with Pool(processes=3) as pool:
        pool.starmap(get_data, pool_tuple)
```

What I want is that I should be able to put the result in the queue from different processes. 
The error I am getting is: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance

Am I doing something wrong in the way I am passing the queue object? Since if Process supports this, so should the Pool method be able to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using [`Manager()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) like this:

```py
from multiprocessing import Manager, Pool


def get_data(pageNo, q):
    q.put(pageNo * pageNo)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = Manager()
    q = m.Queue()
    p = {}
    no_pages = 5
    pool_tuple = [(x, q) for x in range(1, no_pages)]
    with Pool(processes=3) as pool:
        pool.starmap(get_data, pool_tuple)
    for i in range(1, no_pages):
        print("result", i, ":", q.get())
```

Output:

```
result 1 : 1
result 2 : 4
result 3 : 9
result 4 : 16
```

Comment: Why does the Manager make the difference here?

Comment: @quamrana from the docs I linked to: `A manager object returned by Manager() controls a server process which holds Python objects and allows other processes to manipulate them using proxies.`  I personally don't have a slight idea on how it is implemented internally.

Comment: same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/9928191/3185459

Comment: oh wow @RomanPerekhrest, and exact duplicate, I didn't even check before answering... sorry.

Comment: There is a left-over `p = {}` without any usage I think?