# How do I get child process PIDs when using ProcessPoolExecuter?

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I'm using  ProcessPoolExecutor  context manager to run several Kafka consumers in parallel. I need to store the process IDs of the child processes so that later, I can cleanly terminate those processes. I have such code:

```
Class MultiProcessConsumer:
    ...

    def run_in_parallel(self):
        parallelism_factor = 5

        with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            processes = [executor.submit(self.consume) for _ in range(parallelism_factor)]
            # It would be nice If I could write [process.pid for process in processes] to a file here.

    def consume(self):
        while True:
            for message in self.kafka_consumer:
                do_stuff(message)
```

I know I can use `os.get_pid()` in the consume method to get PIDs. But, handling them properly (in case of constant shutting down or starting up of consumers) requires some extra work.

How would you propose that I get and store PIDs of the child processes in such a context?

Answer (score 5):

`os.getpid()` seems to be the way to go. Just pass them through a Queue or Pipe in combination with maybe some random UUID that you pass to the process before to identify the PID.

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import os
import time 
import uuid
#from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import multiprocessing
import queue
#The Empty exception in in Queue, multiprocessing borrows 
#it from there

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908781/sharing-a-result-queue-among-several-processes     
m = multiprocessing.Manager()
q = m.Queue()

def task(n, queue, uuid):
    my_pid = os.getpid()
    print("Executing our Task on Process {}".format(my_pid))
    queue.put((uuid, my_pid))
    time.sleep(n)
    return n * n

def main():

    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers = 3) as executor:

        some_dict = {}
        for i in range(10):
            print(i)

            u = uuid.uuid4()
            f = executor.submit(task, i, q, u)
            some_dict[u] = [f, None] # PID not known here

            try:
                rcv_uuid, rcv_pid = q.get(block=True, timeout=1)
                some_dict[rcv_uuid][1] = rcv_pid # store PID
            except queue.Empty as e:
                print('handle me', e)
            print('I am', rcv_uuid, 'and my PID is', rcv_pid)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I believe it should be `os.getpid()` instead of `os.get_pid()`.

Comment: Yes, code was correct, but description had the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Although this field is private, you could use the field in PoolProcessExecutor `self._processes`. The code snippet below shows how to use this variable.

```
import os

from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from concurrent.futures import wait

nb_processes = 100

executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(nb_processes )

futures = [executor.submit(os.getpid) for _ in range(nb_processes )]
wait(futures)
backends = list(map(lambda x: x.result(), futures))

assert len(set(backends)) == nb_processes
```

In the case above, an assertion error is raised. This is because a new task can reuse the forked processes in the pool. You cannot know all forked process IDs through the method you memtioned. Hence, you can do as:

```
import os

from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from concurrent.futures import wait

nb_processes = 100

executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(nb_processes )

futures = [executor.submit(os.getpid) for _ in range(nb_processes )]
wait(futures)
backends = list(map(lambda x: x.result(), futures))

assert len(set(executor._processes.keys())) == nb_processes 
print('all of PID are: %s.' % list(executor._processes.keys()))
```

If you don't want to destroy the encapsulation, you could inhert the ProcessPoolExecutor and create a new property for that.