# multiprocessing on a single queue

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am a bitt struggled with multiprocessing philosophy in Python. To test my knowledge I thought of a multiprocessed programm that computes the prime decomposition of an integer.
It goes as follows. Put the integer in a queue. I then have a function that dequeue and search for a (prime) divisor of it. If one is found, the complementary integer is put back in the queue. How can I make this work. For the moment I have this :

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def f(queue, decomp):
    x = queue.get()
    prime = True
    for i in range(2, x):
        if (x % i) == 0:
            decomp.put(i)
            prime = False
            queue.put(x // i)
            break
    if prime:
        decomp.put(x)

class Num:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.queue = mp.Queue()
        self.queue.put(n)
        self.decomposition = mp.Queue()

    def run(self):
        with mp.Pool(4) as pool:
            pool.apply_async(f, (self.queue, self.decomposition))
```

It raises

```
RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance
```

What is the standard way to make this ? (I know there may be better way to give the prime decomposition)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sharing a result queue among several processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908781/sharing-a-result-queue-among-several-processes)

Comment: I red the accepted answer. Is there a way to use the second answer, not based on ```Manager``` ?

Answer (score 2):

In order to use `multiprocessing.Queue`, you need to pass it to each child process as the point they are created (so they get "inherited"), rather than passing them as parameters to `apply_async`. If you're on Linux, you can do this by declaring them in the global scope, instead of as intance variables on the `Num` class - they will get inherited via the forking process:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

queue = mp.Queue()
decomposition = mp.Queue()

def f():
    x = queue.get()
    prime = True
    for i in range(2, x):
        if (x % i) == 0:
            decomposition.put(i)
            prime = False
            queue.put(x // i)
            break
    if prime:
        decomposition.put(x)
    
class Num:
    def __init__(self, n):
        queue.put(n)

    def run(self):
        with mp.Pool(4) as pool:
            pool.apply(f)
```

On Windows, it is a bit more involved, since it does not have support for forking. Instead, you have to use the `init` and `initargs` keyword parameters on the `Pool` constructor to pass the queues to the child processes, and then declare them as global variables inside the initializer function you provide. This will put the the queues in the global scope of your worker processes, allowing you to use them in the functions you pass to all `Pool` methods (`map`/`map_async`, `apply`/`apply_async`).

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def f():
    x = queue.get()
    prime = True
    for i in range(2, x):
        if (x % i) == 0:
            decomp.put(i)
            prime = False
            queue.put(x // i)
            break
    if prime:
        decomp.put(x)


def init(q, d):
    # Put the queues in the global scope of the worker processes
    global queue, decomp
    queue = q
    decomp = d        

class Num:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.queue = mp.Queue()
        self.queue.put(n)
        self.decomposition = mp.Queue()

    def run(self):
        with mp.Pool(4, initializer=init, initargs=(self.queue, self.decomposition)) as pool:
            pool.apply(f)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In the Linux case, what is the use of the init function ? A side question. Do you have any reference on multiprogramming, I am a bit lost and the documentation of Python is not reallly helpful.

Comment: It was an error to include the `init` function in the Linux example; I've removed it. Sorry, I don't know of any resources that cover the correct use of `multiprocessing`. I agree that the documentation is difficult to digest and doesn't explicitly cover a lot of stuff that it probably should (like the fact that `multiprocessing.Queue` can't be pickled, and what you should do instead). The rules and best practices for working with `multiprocessing` are not very intuitive, so I think they really need something very example-driven to help people understand it, but that's not what's there now.