# Correct way to implement producer consumer pattern in python multiprocessing Pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing, producer-consumer

I want to implement [producer-consumer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) by using [`multiprocessing.pool.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool)

Since the [`JoinableQueue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.JoinableQueue) cannot be used in `Pool` (would claim `RuntimeError: JoinableQueue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance`), I have to use [`multiprocessing.Manager()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.sharedctypes.multiprocessing.Manager) inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9928191/).

The question is: now the program may hang when consumer jobs are larger than producer jobs.

```py
import queue
import random
from multiprocessing import Manager, Pool


def consumer(q):
    while True:
        try:
            res = q.get(block=False)
            if res is None:
                break
            print(f'Consume {res}')
        except queue.Empty:
            pass


def producer(q, food):
    for i in range(2):
        res = f'{food} {i}'
        print(f'Produce {res}')
        q.put(res)
    q.put(None) # sentinel


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool() as pool:
        jobs = 2
        foods = ['apple', 'banana', 'melon', 'salad']
        q = Manager().Queue()
        [pool.apply_async(func=consumer, args=(q, )) for _ in range(jobs + 1)]  # would hang

        # would not hang only when the consumer jobs is equal or less than the producer jobs
        # [pool.apply_async(func=consumer, args=(q, )) for _ in range(jobs)] 

        [
            pool.apply_async(func=producer, args=(q, random.choice(foods)))
            for _ in range(jobs)
        ]

        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

Seems like those *extra* consumers can't get the *sentinel* and just wait there forever.

So what's the elegant way to implement the producer-consumer pattern in `multiprocessing.pool.Pool`?

Or is it only possible with [`multiprocessing.Process`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) + `JoinableQueue`?

Comment: your producer puts only one "sentinel" to the queue, how multiple consumers could get it in case of single producer?

Comment: @NobbyNobbs Actually I don't know whether put sentinel into the queue is the **correct** way to implement the producer-consumer pattern in this `Pool` case. I can put *a lot of* sentinels to *notify* those consumers, but is that a good way? Or is that an elegant way? And it seems that I can't put the sentinel back into the queue when a consumer get one since it would mislead the other consumers?

Comment: Look at `multiprocessing.Event` for consumers cancellation

Comment: @NobbyNobbs Thanks, but `Event` is more like a pause-restart mechanism?

Answer (score 3):

Seems like using `multiprocessing.Process` + `JoinableQueue` is a more elegant way.

```py
import queue
import random
from multiprocessing import JoinableQueue, Process


def consumer(q: JoinableQueue):
    while True:
        try:
            res = q.get(block=False)
            print(f'Consume {res}')
            q.task_done()
        except queue.Empty:
            pass


def producer(q: JoinableQueue, food):
    for i in range(2):
        res = f'{food} {i}'
        print(f'Produce {res}')
        q.put(res)
    q.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    foods = ['apple', 'banana', 'melon', 'salad']
    jobs = 2
    q = JoinableQueue()

    producers = [
        Process(target=producer, args=(q, random.choice(foods)))
        for _ in range(jobs)
    ]

    # daemon=True is important here
    consumers = [
        Process(target=consumer, args=(q, ), daemon=True)
        for _ in range(jobs * 2)
    ]

    # + order here doesn't matter
    for p in consumers + producers:
        p.start()

    for p in producers:
        p.join()
```

Comment: Why there are `import queue` and no `daemon=True` in producers?

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use a `multiprocessing.JoinableQueue` by having your process pool workers accessing it as a global variable that gets initialized using a pool initializer:

```py
import multiprocessing

def init_pool(input_q, output_q):
    global in_q, out_q
    in_q = input_q
    out_q = output_q


def worker():
    print(type(in_q))


# required by Windows
if __name__ == '__main__':
    in_q = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
    out_q = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(in_q, out_q))
    pool.apply(worker)
```

Prints:

```
<class 'multiprocessing.queues.JoinableQueue'>
```

Answer (score 1):

In [funkid's self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67364817/16391498),
when using `JoinableQueue`, you don't have to send/receive the trailing `None` in producer/consumer anymore. All producers wait until all of the items in the queue have been consumed **completely** (after the final `task_done`), then joined by the main process.

As pointed out by [@Koby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7916557/koby),
`daemon=True` is important because it allows the consumers (blocked by the empty queue) to be killed when the main process terminates.

Modified program:

```py
import random
from multiprocessing import JoinableQueue, Process


def consumer(q: JoinableQueue):
    while True:
        res = q.get()
        print(f'Consume {res}')
        q.task_done()


def producer(q: JoinableQueue, food):
    for i in range(2):
        res = f'{food} {i}'
        print(f'Produce {res}')
        q.put(res)
    q.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    foods = ['apple', 'banana', 'melon', 'salad']
    jobs = 2
    q = JoinableQueue()

    producers = [
        Process(target=producer, args=(q, random.choice(foods)))
        for _ in range(jobs)
    ]

    # daemon=True is important here
    consumers = [
        Process(target=consumer, args=(q, ), daemon=True)
        for _ in range(jobs * 2)
    ]

    # + order here doesn't matter
    for p in consumers + producers:
        p.start()

    for p in producers:
        p.join()
```